# Prevent Changes during long running job

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Our Web Application uses an .net-core web api running on a loab balancer and an angular client. We access the DB using EF core.
We have a long running background-task that does a great amount of calculation and takes about 2-3 hours to do so, but will only be initiated by administrators of the application 3-4 times a year. 
While the job is running we want to prevent users from adding/editing/deleting data and our client told us its even fine if the application is not avaliable for the duration as they will mostly do it overnight.
The easiest way to do this is to redirect users to an informationpage while the job is running but I have found no way of actually getting to the information if the task is running or not.

- I could set a flag whether the job is running or not and just check that flag at every request but I found no way to access an applicationwide state.
- I cannot save a flag to the DB because while the transaction is commiting at the end of the job (~1 hour) we cannot read from the DB

What baffles me most is that I have not found a single article or question about a problem like that which doesn't seem to be too outlandish to me, so I guess I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: this is offtopic, i guess, but you can use dedicated Redis server to store this flag

Comment: use hangfire instead of a background task and check if the job is running? If you are behind a load balancer, how do you guarantee only 1 instance is executing the job?

Comment: While it does run in the background we do push the progress to the UI with signalR, so I don't know if hangfire will work for that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to store the value for your "Maintenance Mode" in a Singleton class on the server. (No database call needed). The value will remain there for as long as the server is actively running.

Comment: They told about load balancing. You can't share singleton over different machines.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I completely skipped over the load balancer part :-s Maybe a seperate database to store the values? or possibly using a distributed caching mechanism like https://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/

Comment: So just use distributed cache instead. The core of this answer is still valid.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easier way, but a distributed cache seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If distributed cache (as already mentioned) is not an option, you can run long running task in (uniquely) named transaction and then the check list of active transactions to determine if task is still running.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely dependent on your setup but a simple way to approach this problem might be to make it the long-running job's responsibility to divert traffic from your site while it is running, and then undo that once it is finished.

As an example, if you were running this with an old-school .NET site in `IIS` the job could drop an `app_offline.htm` file into the site folder, run, then delete it again. Your setup is different, but if you could do something similar with your load-balancer (configure it to serve some static file instead of routing the requests to your servers) then it could work for you.